# Using TypeScript generic as its own argument, or specifying it as its own default argument

Tags: typescript, generics

I have the following `ItemBase` interface and multiple other recursive `xItem` interfaces that extend from it:

```js
interface ItemBase<Children extends ItemBase<Children>> {
  x: string;
  y: number;
  children: Children[];
}

interface FooItem extends ItemBase<FooItem> {
  foo: boolean;
}

interface BarItem extends ItemBase<BarItem> {
  bar: "b" | "a" | "r";
}
```

I would now like to reference `ItemBase` with itself as its own argument:

```js
const transformItem = (item: ItemBase<ItemBase>) => { ... }
//                                    ^
// TS2314: Generic type 'ItemBase ' requires 1 type argument(s).
```

but this doesn't work, because since I didn't specify the inner `ItemBase`'s argument (and obviously can't keep specifying those to infinity).

Even better would be providing itself as `ItemBase`'s default argument... I tried two ways, but each of them runs into its own error:

```js
interface ItemBase<Children extends ItemBase<Children> = ItemBase<Children>> {
//                                                                ^
// TS2744: Type parameter defaults can only reference previously declared type parameters.
  x: string;
  y: number;
  children: Children[];
}
```

```js
interface ItemBase<Children extends ItemBase<Children> = ItemBase> {
//                                                       ^
// TS2716: Type parameter 'Children' has a circular default.
  x: string;
  y: number;
  children: Children[];
}
```

An obvious workaround would be creating a separate interface to express my self-referencing base:

```js
interface BaseItem extends ItemBase<BaseItem> {}
const transformItem = (item: BaseItem) => { ... }
```

but that's more of a hack, since the other items don't really inherit from it.

What are some other options I have?

Comment: What kind of syntax is `const (transformItem: ItemBase<ItemBase>) => { ... }`?  To what is `const` applying?

Comment: @jcalz This is my signature "brainfart syntax" :). I corrected the mistake in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your use case, you might want to use [polymorphic `this` types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types).  In an `interface` or `class` declaration, you can use the type named `this` to refer to the "current" subtype.  It is as if `this` is an "implicit" [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter which behaves similarly to the recursive constraint (a.k.a. ["F-bounded polymorphism"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification)) in  `interface Foo<T extends Foo<T>>`.  It frees you from having to explicitly use generics:

```
interface ItemBase {
    x: string;
    y: number;
    children: this[];
}

interface FooItem extends ItemBase {
    foo: boolean;
}

interface BarItem extends ItemBase {
    bar: "b" | "a" | "r";
}
```

And to see it in action, here are some possible uses:

```
const fooItem: FooItem = {
    x: "a",
    y: 1,
    foo: true,
    children: [{
        x: "b", y: 2, foo: true, children: []
    }]
}

function processItem(item: ItemBase) {
    console.log(item.x.toUpperCase());
    console.log(item.y.toFixed(2));
    item.children.forEach(i => processItem(i));
}

processItem(fooItem); // A, 1,00, B, 2.00
```

There are some situations in which polymorphic `this` is hard to use, but without more concrete use cases in the question I'm not sure if you will run into them.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)